# algorithm to get all combinations of splitting up N items into K bins

Tags: algorithm, recursion, permutation

Assuming I have a list of elements `[1,2,3,4,]` and a number of bins (let's assume 2 bins), I want to come up with a list of all combinations of splitting up items 1-4 into the 2 bins. Solution should look something like this

`[{{1}, {2,3,4}}, {{2}, {1,3,4}}, {{3}, {1,2,4}}, {{4}, {1,2,3}},
 {{1,2}, {3,4}}, {{1,3}, {2,4}}, {{1,4}, {2,3}}, {{}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {}}]`

Also, order does matter -- I didn't write out all the return values but `{{1, 2, 3}, {4}}` is a different solution from `{{3, 2, 1}, {4}}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n)

Comment: Are you missing {{}, {1,2,3,4}}?

Comment: Yes, that should be included in the solution, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common approach is as follows.

If you have, say, `K` bins, then add `K-1` special values to your initial array. I will use the `-1` value assuming that it never occurs in the initial array; you can choose a different value.

So for your example the initial array becomes `arr=[1,2,3,4,-1]`; if `K` were, say, `4`, the array would be `arr=[1,2,3,4,-1,-1,-1]`.

Now list all the permutations of array `arr`. For each permutation, treat all `-1`s as bin separators, so all the elements befors the first `-1` go to the first bin (in that particular order), all the elements between first and second `-1` go to the second bin, and so on.

For example:

```
[-1,1,2,3,4] -> {{}, {1,2,3,4}}
[2,1,3,-1,4] -> {{2,3,4}, {4}}
[3,1,2,-1,4] -> {{3,1,2}, {4}}
[1,3,-1,2,4] -> {{1,3}, {2,4}}
```

and so on.

Generating all permutation is a standard task (see, for example, [Permutations in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960908/permutations-in-javascript)), and splitting an array by `-1`s should be easy.

Comment: very interesting -- will take a look at this solution